# Upload file to RESTful Webservice with HTML5 File API

Tags: java, javascript, rest, file-upload, jax-rs

I'm trying to upload a file with HTML5 File API to a Java RESTful WebService. When I try to upload a gif image the service is receiving an InputStream and I can write that stream to the server file system. Unfortunately something is going wrong because the created image is bigger (689 Byte) than the source file (512 Byte). This is what I have already:

JavaScript:

```
var doc = document.documentElement;
doc.ondrop = function (event) {
  event.preventDefault && event.preventDefault();

  // now do something with:
  var files = event.dataTransfer.files;
  var formData = new FormData();
  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    formData.append('file', files[i]);
  }

  // now post a new XHR request
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', 'rs/media/upload', true);
  xhr.onload = function () {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      console.log('all done: ' + xhr.status);
    } else {
      console.log('Something went terribly wrong...');
    }
  };

  xhr.send(formData);
  return false;
};
```

Java RESTful Service:

```
  @POST
  @Path("upload")
  @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
  public Response uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream) throws IOException
  {
    if (uploadedInputStream == null) {
      return Response.status(Response.Status.PRECONDITION_FAILED).build();
    }

    writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, MEDIA_BASE_PATH + "/test.gif");

    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
  }

  private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream, String uploadedFileLocation)
  {

    try {
      OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
      int read = 0;
      byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

      out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
      while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        out.write(bytes, 0, read);
      }
      out.flush();
      out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Could someone please tell me what is wrong here? The WebService is still rudimentary so please don't wonder that I'm using absolute target paths.

Thanks,
Gerry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed from Jersey to RESTeasy and now everything is working as expected. Here is my new REST method:

```
  @POST
  @Path("upload")
  @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
  public Response uploadFile(@MultipartForm FileUploadForm form) throws IOException
  {
    if (form == null) {
      return Response.status(Response.Status.PRECONDITION_FAILED).build();
    }

    Files.write(Paths.get(MEDIA_BASE_PATH + "/test.gif"), form.getData());

    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
  }
```

Source: http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/file-upload-example-in-resteasy/